Make rsync show the ammount of data to be transfered per file
Sometimes you want to have information about the synchronization job that you are about to start, perhaps a job will take so much time that it is better to run it over night, rather than at once. You can have rsync give you a summary of the job asked of it by using the options --dry-run and --stats like so:
rsync --dry-run --stats "$source" "$target"

You can also make rsync be more verbose about the job by adding the option --verbose one or more times,  e.g.
rsync -vv --dry-run --stats "$source" "$target"

I find myself wanting to know which files will require the most data in the transfer, perhaps some of them can be excluded, using the --exclude option.
It is possible to list the files to be transferred using
rsync -v --dry-run "$source" "$target"

You could also add more verbosity and exclude files not to be synced using something like
rsync -vvvvv --dry-run "$source" "$target" | grep -v uptodate

Sadly, not even this will produce any information about the amount of data required per file, and so I wonder:
Is there a, preferably simple, way to make rsync print the amount of transferred data that each file will require to make the target up to date?
